# How can I sync only the files I have in my local?

Tags: rsync

I already synced with rsync the files from a remote server to my local.
When I run the rsync, I excluded several folders and after the sync, I removed some files from the local version.

How can I resync, so that I can have the latest version, of the files I have in local and ignore the one I deleted from my local and the one I excluded since the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just deleting the local files you could additionally add them to an rsync exclude list. A wrapper for the remove command could do that automatically.

Comment: I didn't thought about that